# Generating a AWS Signature (ShipLogic)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, authentication, signature

So I'm implementing ship-logic's API into my program and have never worked with AWS authentication.
Did my research on the documentation and done the following:

```
<?php
$host = "api.shiplogic.com";
$accessKey = '******';
$secretKey = '******';
$requestUrl = 'https://api.shiplogic.com';
$uri = '/rates';
$httpRequestMethod = 'POST';
$data = '{"collection_address": {"company": "Kenesis Test","street_address": " 32 Goud Street, Goedeburg, Benoni","local_area": "Benoni","city": "Johannesburg","country": "ZA","code": "1501"},"delivery_address": {"street_address": "17 bloomberg street","local_area": "minnebron","city": "brakpan","code": "1541"},"parcels": [{"submitted_length_cm": 1,"submitted_width_cm": 1,"submitted_height_cm": 1,"submitted_weight_kg": 0.1}],"declared_value": 99}';;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\Signature\SignatureV4;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use Psr\Http\Client\ClientInterface;

$signature = new SignatureV4('execute-api', 'af-south-1');
$credentials = new Credentials($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey);
$psr7Request = new Request($httpRequestMethod, $requestUrl.$uri, ["content-type"=>"application/json"], $data);
$client = new Client([$requestUrl, 'timeout' => 30]);
$sr = $signature->signRequest($psr7Request, $credentials);
$response = $client->send($sr);

//var_dump($response);
?>
```

Now its a simple piece of code but I'm constantly getting a 403 response.
When I do the exact same request with PostMan, the response came back successfully.

Can any AWS guru assist me and point out if I am doing anything wrong??
Assistance would be highly appreciated.

P.S, I'm using sandbox credentials here, no worries.

Comment: If the 403 is returned from the PSR7 request you are making to the shiplogic api, check if the request headers you send in your php request match those from postman.
Its probably got something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a headers issue. You need to include the following headers when sending the request through.

```
$amzDate = date('Ymd\THis\Z');
$headers = [
'X-Amz-Date'   => $amzDate,
'Cookie'       => 'XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM',
'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your variable names.

```
$credentials = new Credentials($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey);
```

should be

```
$credentials = new Credentials($accessKey, $secretKey);
```

Once you fix those the code works 100%.